Module isomorphism of tensor products
Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra, and $M$ be a simple $A$-module. Is there any isomorphism between $\text{Hom}_A(M,M^n) \otimes_K M$ and
$\text{End}_A(M)\otimes_K M^n$?
Can we conclude they are module isomorphic using hom-tensor adjunction?
Would you also tell me if this question is in the field of homological algebra or if it is a typical question in module theory? I am asking this so that I determine which area I need to learn to answer this question.

Yes, they're isomorphic, every additive functor commutes with finite direct sums (this is a good exercise; it is not necessary to even know that hom preserves limits and tensor preserves colimits). The tensor-hom adjunction is not really relevant.

Would you explain more? Do you mean $\text{Hom}_A(M,M^n)\otimes M \cong \text{End}_A(M)^n\otimes M \cong \text{End}_A(M) \otimes M^n $?

Yes, that's what I mean.
